# Interview Question: Virtualization and software quality assurance

Tags: virtualization

How do you automate (in testing) the process of making your system fail and recover from the failure, and also you must make sure time stamp is maintained each time the system recovers?

I was asked this question in an interview. I know this question is little vague, I guess interviewer was trying to test my virtualization skills.

Comment: This is very, very difficult to answer because the steps and scenarios vary wildly. VMWare have a product called Site Recovery Manager which automates all of this for you, but if you're using, say, Xeon or KVM then the procedure is entirely different.

Comment: The interviewer was much interested in Xen hypervisor, he was more interested in test automation of system failure

Comment: That question is very broad, you would need a lot more information to find out exactly what it is they were looking for. I'm guessing the interviewer wanted to see if you would probe for more information or not.

Comment: @cpgascho yeah agree, i probed him lot information, like i said we can run monitor process which has time stamp or modifying the code where the process can die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I'd use the hypervisors' API to monitor the VM status, while killing it's process, to simulate failure. The API based monitoring will write logs with timestamps.

This can be the broad answer, as for specifics - it would depend on what hypervisor and management are used